# Set background in autocomplete view android

Tags: android

How i can set an image as background of my autocomlete list?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="#000">
</TextView>

AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_friends);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, friendsListNameOrder);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

in your xml put the background attribute for your TextView:

```
<TextView android:background="@drawable/your_img" ... other attributes />
```

Comment: I want set background of page where the textview is contained....no background of drop down list.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do? If you want to change the background of the TextView you do it the way I pointed out in the answer, if you want to change the background of something else then set the `android:background` attribute of that other view. Try to clarify your question better?

Comment: You have never use the autocomoplete texview in android?

Comment: he is trying to ask how to set a background of AutoCompleteListView which will be opened when user start typing anything.

Answer (score 1):

This might help someone else!.. I think what you were looking for was this :

```
textView.setDropDownBackgroundResource();
```

OR

```
searchBox.setDropDownBackgroundDrawable();
```